# Audio Recorder opening on startup in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: startup, audio-recording

I can't find a way to make the Audio Recorder not open up on startup. I don't remember where I got it from, it has a red icon and says: "Easy-to-use audio recording tool" on the description.

Comment: Open `startup applications` from `DASH` and check for that program. Uncheck it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `DASH` and search for `Startup Applications` and look for that program and `uncheck` it. That should stop its launch at start up.